# Spring repositories causing unresolved circular reference

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data

I am attempting to upgrade my Springboot application to the latest version (which at the time of writing this is 2.6.6). I am running the gauntlet of fixing circular references, and am getting into weird issues where our MongoRepository interfaces are causing `BeanCurrentlyInCreationException`'s. This is happening with repositories defined within the service, as well as ones pulled in via libraries.

Below is an example of a component that is throwing an error (written in Kotlin):

```
@Repository
interface UserViewRepo: MongoRepository<UserView, String> {
    fun findByUsername(username: String): Optional<UserView>
}

@Component
class UserViewHandler(private val userViewRepo: UserViewRepo) {
    // ...
}
```

The above, in it's current form, results in the following exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userViewHandler' defined in file [/Users/user/Lifeway/customer/refactor/cscp-user_service/build/classes/kotlin/main/com/lifeway/views/UserViewHandler.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userViewRepo': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?

...

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userViewRepo': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
```

**What I have tried**

- I added a configuration class that would wire the bean up for me, instead of relying on the `@Component` annotation to resolve the constructor
- I added the `@Lazy` annotation before my repo argument.

The problem with both of the above solutions is that for either one, I would have to touch a large number of components or manually wire up a large number of beans. It's a lot of work, and it just makes me thing that there has to be a better way. On top of this, as I mentioned before, this is happening with external libraries as well. So if there are components defined there, I have to either

- manually exclude them from my component scan and then wire the beans up within my service.
- edit the libraries to include the `@Lazy` annotation

This is only happening with repositories, specifically `MongoRepository` interfaces, in my case. Has anyone encountered this?

Comment: may be issue is somewhere else. Have you pasted the actual code? or does these beans depend on some other beans as well?  how is `UserViewHandler ` used in other beans?

Comment: It isn't used directly by any other beans. The service uses the Axon framework, so it does get referenced internally using some of the event processing mechanics. But I don't think that is being done using Spring's autowiring.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed this is the problem of circular dependency in your code. Circular References Prohibited by Default in spring boot version 2.6. And of course its tedious task to remove all the circular dependencies in spring boot 2.6 from 2.5 and there is no short cut apart from find and resolve. The temporary solution is to restore 2.5’s behavior, set the following in .properties/yml,

```
spring: 
  main:
   allow-circular-references: true
```

Or if you don't want it in config file, change in main class like below -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Properties props = new Properties();
    // This property is used to allow the circular dependencies between the beans/classes.
    props.put("spring.main.allow-circular-references", "true");

    new SpringApplicationBuilder(TestApplication.class)
            .properties(props).build().run(args);

}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was afraid of. I was trying to avoid using this property, because, according to things that I am reading, circular references are indicative of "bad architecture". Personally, I have enjoyed the freedom that Spring's autowiring mechanic allows. It really makes me wonder why this change was made (and makes me question whether or not I should feel bad for using the cheaty annotation).

Comment: Yes we also faced the same problem. In our project as well, we thought to make the changes but it was not easy task. We have already planed to do this activity but again as i said we don't have a shortcut, we have to follow 'find and resolve' strategy only.